# Text won't appear in external bitmap/jpeg file. Drawatpoint not working in current context?

Tags: ios, text, core-graphics

Fairly new to CoreGraphics but got the hang of the basics. Trying to write to an external file (not the screen of the phone). All grids appear but it will not render the text using drawAtPoint. Whatever I try it just doesn't do it!

Here's my code which it fired when viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    CGFloat width = 312;
    CGFloat height = 482;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerPixel    = 4;
    size_t bytesPerRow      = (width * bitsPerComponent * bytesPerPixel + 7) / 8;
    size_t dataSize         = bytesPerRow * height;

    unsigned char *data = malloc(dataSize);
    memset(data, 0, dataSize);

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 
                                                 bitsPerComponent, 
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, 
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    // Flip coordinate system
    CGRect bounds = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -bounds.size.height);

    //  And now the magic happens...

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0,0,312,482));

    int tableTop=54;
    int cellsPerColumn=26;
    int cellHeight=15;

    [@"Title" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(8, 8) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:9.0f]];   //  Doesn't print text on  screen?!

    for(int a=1;a<cellsPerColumn+1;a++)
    {
        CGContextStrokeRect(context, CGRectMake(8,(tableTop+cellHeight*(a+1)),60,cellHeight));
        CGContextStrokeRect(context, CGRectMake(66,(tableTop+cellHeight*(a+1)),85,cellHeight));
        CGContextStrokeRect(context, CGRectMake(159,(tableTop+cellHeight*(a+1)),60,cellHeight));
        CGContextStrokeRect(context, CGRectMake(217,(tableTop+cellHeight*(a+1)),85,cellHeight));
    }



    //  Wrap up context and produce the image...



    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *result = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef] retain];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    free(data);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"user_images/myImage.jpg"];

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(result)];
    [imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I'm tearing my hair out on this one, it's got so be something about setting the context with which to render the text into or something simple like that. Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

Utility methods, such as drawAtPoint: will only work for drawing within the current graphics context, commonly the context provide during a drawRect callback of a subclassed NSView.  Or you can try the setCurrentContext: method with the bitmap context you created.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer but got me thinking maybe i'm going about this all the wrong way.

I'm trying to generate image as a file on the phone to contain drawing objects, images and text using the NS utility commands such as drawAtPoint. The dimensions of this file are beyond the bounds of the screen and the file needs to be produced programatically and behind-the-scenes so the user does not need to see it. I also would like control over the resolution of the resulting image (pref 300dpi).

There must be a straightforward way to do this? Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Rich